# concatenate list items only if item is text

Tags: python

I want to convert my string to a list and concatenate items only if the item is a text.

For example:

```
string = "123 text 4 text text text 800 text"

l = []
for i in string.split():
    if i[0].isalpha:
        l.append(i)
```

What I want

```
l = ["123", "text", "4", "text text text", "800", "text"]
```

What I have

```
l = ["123", "text", "4", "text", "text", "text", "800", "text"]
```

I want to concat all text items between numbers into one list item

Comment: What specifically was the difficulty you encountered when you tried to do this? Do you not know how to distinguish text from non-text? Do you not know how to concatenate two strings?

Answer (score 5):

```
import itertools as it    

string = "123 text 4 text text text 800 text"
l = [" ".join(group)
     for _, group in it.groupby(
         string.split(), key=lambda s: s[0].isalpha())]
```

Result:

```
>>> l
['123', 'text', '4', 'text text text', '800', 'text']
```